# How can I get in Australia without complete education?

Tags: working-visas, australia

I am an ACCA Part II qualified student and now working in Changhong Ruba Trading Pvt Ltd, Pakistan as Branch Accountant. My studies are not complete as ACCA Final Level need to be complete but due to some financial reasons I give it a break. Now I want to go to Australia for work. How can I get there and work at my present status?

Comment: What citizenship do you have? Pakistani? There are different visas for different citizens that you might be eligible.  Do you want to work fulltime or would study be an option as well, with part-time work?